# Angular search in model on button click

Tags: angular, button, filter

I have acustom pipe filter that allows me to search in my model the search text and i'm struggling to make it work on button press instead of user input. Right now i'm trying to do it like that:

```
<input [{ngModel}="SearchText" type="text">
```

and i create my data like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let c for char | filter : SearchText">
 <td> {{c.Name}} </td>
</tr>
```

So this works.

And now i try to add something like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="searchText = {Name: Ragnar}">Ragnar</button>
```

And this doesn't work. I also tried:

```
<button type="button" [{ngModel}="SearchText">Ragnar</button>
```

But it doesn't seem to read Ragnar too. Any ideas?

Angular 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes

change

**From**

```
<input [{ngModel}="SearchText" type="text">
```

**To**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="SearchText" type="text">
```

and **`(click)`** instead of **`ng-click`**

```
<button type="button" (click)="searchText = {Name: 'Ragnar'}">Ragnar</button>
```

Comment: It says SearchText.ToLowerCase() is not a function. But i can see he's passing [Object Object]. So probably because the search text when i click on the button isn't a string. How can i change it?

Comment: @John probably because `{Name: Ragnar}` should be `{Name: 'Ragnar'}`

Comment: you need to pass string instead of object just set ragnar

Comment: It still sends [object Object]

Comment: just do (click)="searchText = 'Ragnar'">

Comment: yeah it says 2 min. I'll do it. Thanks for the help!